# Python which itertools module function should I use?

Tags: python, loops, iterator, combinations

Which itertools function (or any function) should I use if I want to achieve this:

Input:

```
arr = [0, 1, 2]
```

Output:

```
[
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 2]
[0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 2, 2]
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2]
]
```

Conditions:

- Length of `r`/`3`
- No combinations of e.g. `1,0,0` and `0,1,0`
- Yes repeating values e.g. `1,1,1` or `0,1,1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print([a for a in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(arr, 3)])
```

Comment: Or just `print(list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(arr, 3)))`